# Encryption software as easy to use as EFS

Tags: encryption, software-rec, efs

Is there any encryption software that works as transparently to the user as the built in EFS?  I am trying to create a relatively secure folder for the users to store documents in, but with some users purchasing their own machines I have run into some with the Home versions of Windows XP, Vista and 7.  For every one else I have enabled EFS on a folder, so all interactions are transparent for them.  For the users without EFS support I'd be willing to look at almost any other software as long as it works just as easily for them, to make the support burden on me less.

Answer (score 2):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is easy to use – just create a file-based volume somewhere in `%USERPROFILE%`, then add it to "Favorite Volumes" and set to automount.

There are downsides, though: first, the volume is of fixed size; second, the software needs to be updated manually.